# Oracle PLSQL type named same as a built-in function

Tags: oracle, plsql

In PLSQL, I have a type named json_value. I built a constructor for this type. Now I am having trouble calling this constructor.

It has the same name as a function in Oracle. Because of this, I believe Oracle interprets calls to my constructor as a call to the function. Is there any way around this without changing the type name?

Comment: Why wouldn't you change the type name if it's clashing and giving you problems? You can probably just prefix it with the owning schema name, but you'll have to do that everywhere, which seems a lot of work for no gain; and it's going to continue to be confusing.

Comment: @Abra - [good idea](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a9434ebb10d09351057cbab77db4f003), but it would probably need to be uppercase, unless it was created as a quoted identifier?

Comment: Just change the type name to something which doesn't clash.

Comment: The problem is, this type is being used in other applications, changing the name of the type would be tough. This problem only occurred since Oracle added a function that has the same name as my type.

Comment: @AlexPoole in the link you posted, the type does work. It works in my program as well all the way up to when the constructor call is used. That's where the problem occurs. I think renaming the type might be the solution. Thanks. If there is another work around, let me know.

Comment: Your version doesn't work with the constructor even when the name is quoted? Not that I'm recommending that approach, but still... maybe you could add a fiddle demonstrating the issue.

Comment: @AlexPoole Hey, I tried it again and it worked!  thank you so much. The only problem now is that when I try to use this type in my other packages, it doesn't recognize this type. For example if I declared the variable (x "JSON_VALUE"), it doesn't work. The program complains that "JSON_VALUE must be a type". I tried using just "json_value" with and without the quotes and "JSON_VALUE" without quotes and they don't work.

Comment: @zack I think you have an interesting question here but it would help if you edit your question and add more information to it, including a fully reproducible test case. Don't just leave some snippets in the comments, people won't read them. (Also, I was able to get a JSON_VALUE type to kind of work by prefacing it with the schema name. But I wasn't able to actually instantiate the type with the default constructor.)

Comment: @JonHeller Ahh alright. I'm new to Stack Overflow. But i'll take what your said into consideration. I'll try to put something up later. Thank you!